# I need the Textarea to output as carriage returns as \r in a string [PHP]

Tags: php, string, forms

I've been hitting my head trying to output my text area to a string which includes carriage returns as \r in a string.

No, I don't want nl2br, I need the physical string.

**Text area text example:**

```
All I want is a 
carriage return
to look like this
```

**And to output when processed in a form in PHP to look like this**

```
echo $_POST['text area'];
```

**The string needs to output like this**

```
All I want is a \rcarriage return \rto look like this
```

I've looked online and all over stackoverflow and cannot find the answer that works.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems you want to replace the newline characters by carriage returns. Wouldn't it work to replace the `\n` characters in `$_POST['text area']` with `\r`?

Comment: either all. I just need to post to an external site that requires it.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean literally `\r`, then use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) and put the second argument in single quotes:

```
<?php
$string = "All I want is a 
carriage return
to look like this";
echo str_replace("
", '\r', $string);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/ucQms)

Otherwise, use double quotes (you'll get the actual new line character)

```
echo str_replace("
", "\r", $string);
```

Comment: It could be a \r or \n anything that the external site requires for a new line.

Comment: I tried that, but when you post a form it loses the format totally.

Comment: `PHP_EOL` would  help.

Comment: How do you mean, "loses the format totally"? Can you give an example of your output? Try @LawrenceCherone 's suggestion!

Comment: I'm lost with PHP_EOL and tried a few demos and cannot get it to work.

Comment: PHP_EOL usefull only on CLI.

Comment: @Karkouch no it's not its a cross-platform version, `\r\n` or `\n`

Comment: @ishegg +1 from me as it answers the OP question but I think the OP is asking the wrong question. OP:`either all. I just need to post to an external site that requires it.` what?

Comment: PHP doc says "The correct 'End Of Line' symbol for this platform." so it means that PHP_EOL'value depends on platform in which the PHP is runing on.

Comment: @VincentValentine I agree with Lawrence here, can you be a little more specific in what you need?

Comment: Ok, I have a textarea input box in my form, when I post with the text. Once it gets picked up as a string it loses the format and everything is on one like. I need it to show the \r or \n in the string once its posted.

Comment: @Karkouch Try doing it from a textarea input and see if it works, it doesnt!

Comment: Works for me with [this](https://3v4l.org/TO55v) code. Obviously you won't be able to run it there, but try it in your server. Notice that you can't have indentation on the `str_replace()` line if you go with the first solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to have a string that is capable of displaying over multiple lines and you want to have it contain a carriage return, then what is actually needed are lines terminating with a carriage return followed by a newline, the way the end of line is expressed in a Windows environment.

Here's an example:

```
<?php
$textarea = <<< HDOC
All I want is a 
carriage return
to look like this
HDOC;

$char = "";
$ascii = ord(PHP_EOL);

if ($ascii == 10) {
     $char = "\\n";
     $replaced = str_replace($char,"\\r".$char,$textarea);
     echo $replaced;
}
```

See [live code](https://3v4l.org/cmK2m#output)

I use two slashes in the code so that PHP understands that I refer to the carriage return character itself, which is composed of a slash and the letter r.  Without the extra slash, PHP would not recognized the slash mark but would instead try to generate a carriage return.

Per the PHP 7 [source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/php.h) in main, specifically in php.h, the end of line symbol refers either to a newline, i.e. "\n" or else a carriage return followed by a newline, i.e. "\r\n".

Incidentally, all data submitted via a POSTed form (as well as a GET) should be considered tainted until validated or filtered, i.e. at minimum you need to do something like this to avoid potential problems, such as cross-site scripting (XSS).

```
<?php echo htmlentities( $_POST['text area'] );
```